# property not found on object Type (custom) xcode

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

the strangest thing happened. Although I don't think I touched anything in that class, suddenly it started telling me it couldn't find an array in a class...

Here are the errors:

basically it cannot access the mutable array in baseobject (custom Car.h type)
(semantic issue: property objectReadyForCoreDatabase not found in object of type CarPacket (false, because it is declared))

```
if([baseObject.objectsReadyForCoreDataBaseInput count]<kLenght )
            {
}
```

car packet .h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "ResponsePacket.h"

    @interface CarPacket : ResponsePacket

    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *objectID;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *objectsReadyForCoreDataBaseInput;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger timeStamp;



@end
```

It is weird because on the same page where I get the error if I type object.objectID it recognizes that but not object.objectReadyForCoreDataBaseInput  (also it just suddenly stopped working)

Please let me know if you have any ideas... Thank you

I tried restoring to previous snapshots and it had no effect... it still showed the error (even though I know on that date it didn't)

Comment: When you say "it doesn't recognize" and later say "it just suddenly stopped working", you have to be more specific. Compiler warnings? If so, which? Exceptions generated when running the app? If so, what precisely was the message on the console? Setting that aside, I'd have to guess that the object pointed to by `baseObject` is not a `CarPacket`. I'd be inclined to put a breakpoint at that line of code, and then examine `baseObject` in the debugger.

Comment: it doesn't allow compiling

Comment: semantic issue: property objectReadyForCoreDatabase not found in object of type CarPacket (false, because it is declared)

Comment: I assume you mean `objectsReadyForCoreDataBaseInput`? Not `objectReadyForCoreDatabase`?

Comment: yes sorry, not copying and pasting, just typing here, but they are the same in the code.  It doesn't auto complete when I start typing object.objectsR    but it does for  object.objectID

Comment: Have you changed the way any of the headers are imported?

Comment: What do you mean ?#import is the same (haven't changed the imports).  I even tried an earlier snapshot d showed the same error, so whatever is the issue doesnt get affected by snapshots

Comment: The code you've shared may not be enough to diagnose the problem... my guess would be either an issue with headers (eg, whatever class your first snippet is doesn't know about the properties of CarPacket.h) or perhaps you haven't cast the baseObject as a CarPacket. Could you share more of where you are calling (and seeing this error?)? There's nothing wrong with your interface.

Comment: If previous snapshots that compiled file aren't anymore, I'd be inclined to restart Xcode and do a "Clean" from the "Product" menu. Etc.

Comment: Ok i have reset the sim, then cleaned, (error persist after clean) then restart, no fix

Comment: I see where  the issue could be improper cast, or not importing properly, but how would it let me create an object, assign an objectid (without errors) but not read the array?

Comment: Ok, I found two of the same file (old and new) in the bundle, and it was reading that file instead... Dumb move...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shared much about the context of where you're making the call (and seeing the error). That said, my guess would be one of two things: The calling class isn't familiar with the receiving class (CarPacket), or, the calling class doesn't know that baseObject is a CarPacket.

Where are you calling from? Make sure the calling class imports the headers. Since I don't know where you're calling from, let's say it's from within UnknownClass:

```
UnknownClass.m

#import UnknownClass.h
#import CarPacket.h // This should make your class familiar

@implementation UnknownClass
```

The other thing is that you need to make sure that at the time you're touching the baseObject, your UnknownClass instance knows that it is dealing with a CarPacket instance, e.g.:

```
- (void)someMethodOfUnknownClass
{

CarPacket *baseObject = (CarPacket *)baseObject; // Cast baseObject if it hasn't been declared as a CarPack in scope...

if([baseObject.objectsReadyForCoreDataBaseInput count]<kLenght )
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok just tried again and it is reading the old version of this file (which no longer exists),how do i make it read the new car packet file?

Comment: Turns out i had the old file still in the bundle so that it was reading that version..., thank you for the suggestions